# scrapy script stops after certain requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapinghub

I have a scrapy script running on scrapinghub. The scraper takes one argument as a csv file where the urls have been stored. The script runs without error, but the problem is that it isn't scraping all the items from the url. I have no idea why this is happening. Also the log gives no information about this. Can anyone give any idea about why this is happening?

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: what's the outcome of your job? (you can check that in the last column of the jobs dashboard)